# Initialize a property in a generic class

Tags: typescript

I would like initialize a generic class property to a default value based on the template type. Is this possible in Typescript? For example:

```
class Foo<T> {
  public x: T;
  constructor() {
    this.x = ???;
  }
}
```

I would like to set `???` such that `(new Foo<number>()).x === 0` and `(new Foo<boolean>).x === false` and `(new Foo<Bar>()).x === null`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript type parameters only exist at compile-time.

It is impossible to change a value based on a type parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of my understanding too. Is it possible to create multiple class implementations that get chosen based on the template type?

Comment: No, once again because the type information is not present at runtime.  You'll have to pass some argument to the constructor to indicate what type you want.  By the time you do that, maybe you might as well pass the initial value itself.